# замена goto в java

Tags: java, goto

можете пожалуйста подсказать как можно заменить goto в данном примере

```
createAccount:
System.out.print("впишите логин и пароль через пробел: ");
login = in.next();
password = in.next();
for(int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++){
    if(accounts.get(i).login == login) {
        System.out.println("простите этот акаунт занят");
        goto createAccount;
        }
    }
accounts.add(new Account(login, password));
```

Comment: Заменить на цикл while, например

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем прямолинейно действовать, то метку можно добавить к циклу и делать `continue <метка>;`. В конце цикла `break;`.

```
    createAccount:
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("впишите логин и пароль через пробел: ");
        String login = in.next();
        String password = in.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); ++i){
            if (accounts.get(i).login.equals(login)) {
                System.out.println("простите этот акаунт занят");
                continue createAccount;
            }
        }
        accounts.add(new Account(login, password));
        break;
    }
```

Чуть лучше выделить поиск аккаунта в отдельную функцию:

```
public static Acccount getAccount(List<Account> accounts, String login) {
    for (Account a : accounts) {
        if (a.login.equals(login)) {
            return a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

...

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("впишите логин и пароль через пробел: ");
        String login = in.next();
        String password = in.next();
        if (getAccount(accounts, login) == null) {
            accounts.add(new Account(login, password));
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("простите этот акаунт занят");
    }
```

**P.S.** В Java не стоит сравнивать строки оператором `==`. Используйте `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

Как известно, `goto` в Java существует исключительно как [зарезервированное слово](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Однако в данном случае использование переходов по метке излишне.

Можно упростить код, переписав его с помощью единственного цикла `do-while` без оператора `break`, сохраняя всю логику.  Также можно избавиться от внутреннего цикла для определения существующего аккаунта, например, используя хэш-таблицу аккаунтов с ключами-логинами вместо списка:

```java
Map<String, Account> accounts = loadExistingAccounts();
boolean accountUsed;
String login;
String password;

do {
    System.out.print("впишите логин и пароль через пробел: ");
    login = in.next();
    password = in.next();
    accountUsed = accounts.containsKey(login);
    if (accountUsed) {
        System.out.println("простите этот акаунт занят");
    }
} while (accountUsed);

accounts.put(login, new Account(login, password));
```